# How can I turn off Unity's online search results?

Tags: 14.04, unity

I've never liked or used any of the suggested results from the quick search bar of Unity (14.04). Just today, when launching my usual gedit program, it started showing me **images of genital mutilation** and other terrible things. How do I turn off this unwanted bloat ware? Obviously if I want to do a web search, I use my browser and the command Ctrl-L.